# Pound Sign Not Displaying Jinja2 (Encoding)

Tags: python, flask

My value in the database looks like this:

```
£40
```

This is part of a longer sentence, in case anyone asks why I'm storing it like this.

When I render the text (Flask/Jinja2/Python2.7.9) I get it like this:

```
\xc2\xa340
```

Why is this?

My call function looks like this:

```
def content_brief_metadata(self):
    try:
        self.cursor.execute("set names utf8;")
        self.cursor.execute('select title, description from metadata')
        return self.cursor.fetchall()
    except Exception as e:
        return e
    finally:
        self.db.close()
```

I just pass the data to the template and that's it.

I've also got the charset of the template to utf-8.

Comment: Jinja2 will escape certain character, the pound sign might be one them, try the safe filter: `{{ value | safe }}`

Comment: This is in place already. So no such luck

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python 2 is tricky when handling unicode as it natively handles binary only. So your pound symbol has been encoded and stored in the DB. You can retrieve it like this:

```
>>> '\xc2\xa340'.decode('utf-8')
u'\xa340'
>>> print('\xc2\xa340'.decode('utf-8'))
£40
```

So there are two places this encoding and decoding could be handled:

Before storing the data. When saving the data if you encode it, then there wouldn't be an issue with the rendering. Something like this (psuedocode):

```
cursor.execute('INSERT INTO metadata VALUES (%s, %s)', name.encode('utf-8), description.encode('utf-8'))
```

Or you can decode the binary, after retrieving the data and before sending into the render_template function:

```
name = result[0].decode('utf-8')
description = result[0].decode('utf-8')
return render_template('template.html', name=name, desc=description)
```

Pick one that will be more convenient to your implementation.